# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libeay32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to have run an opensource project in visual studio 2013. In which I am getting this linker error. I did some google search and found that this library is from open ssl. But I am not getting how to resolve this error.

```
'libeay32.lib' has been added in a project and the same project has error.
```

Please help me !!

Comment: Did you set it up in linker options manually?

Comment: @Markovlaić I did once in linker -> input then "file path.lib" but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is your configuration option set to "All configurations"?

Comment: @Markovlaić yes it is

Comment: Have you tried searching it on the Internet with your fave search engine, before posting the question?

Comment: @Ajay Yes I did. If you found something please let me know because I have done it by replacing the file into solution. still it's not working

Comment: The linker error you gave is wrong.

Comment: @Ajay error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libeay32.lib'

Answer (score 1):

It appears the lib file can't be found. You can add the directory where the libeay32.lib is stored to the "Additional Library Directories" in your project properties.

If it still doesn't work, turn on Verbose logging - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx - and re-build. This will show you all library paths that are searched for the library and that may give you a clue.

Answer (score -1):

you can move libeay32.lib to your source code directory